# Visual artifacts in LWJGL (OpenGL) when rendering transparent 2D images

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, transparency, lwjgl

I am using LWJGL to make a 2D game and my transparent textures have visual artifacts in them when rendered onto the screen.
[image: How it is supposed to look like]

[image: What is looks like in game]

The top image is how it is supposed to look like, and the bottom one is how it looks like in game. These visual artifacts are even bigger on larger images. I have tried turning off texture wrapping and I've tried changing the MIN and MAG filter to GL_LINEAER.

This is what my fragment shader looks like:

```
#version 430

uniform sampler2D sampler;
uniform float opacities[5];
uniform int opacityIndex;

in vec2 tex_coords;

out vec4 out_Color;

void main() {
    out_Color = texture2D(sampler, tex_coords);
    out_Color.a *= opacities[opacityIndex];
}
```

The opacities are all 1f when rendering, and I've tried removing the last line of the main method all togehter but the artifacts still appear.

How do I get rid of these visual artifacts?

EDIT: I forgot to add that when I upscale or downscale some of the images, the artifacts disappear, but they shouldn't be where they are in the first place since the one shown here is not being scaled at all to begin with.

Comment: Did you enable mipmaps? When it generates the mipmaps, there is a tendency for some bleed over the edges on some textures due to the reduced pixel count. One of the easiest solutions is to just add a couple extra pixels on the edges (either in code or the image file) to avoid the problem. However, I highly doubt this is the recommended solution. The proper solution is probably to generate the mipmaps in a way that it knows where the boundaries between sprites (letters in your case) are so it can avoid bleed.

Comment: @Locke I am not using mipmapping. The game is in a very early stage right now so the texture rendering is very basic and straight forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These artefacts seem to be caused by linear interpolation in combination with repeat wrapping. With this modes, a texture coordinate of 0 will be an interpolation of the first texel with the last texel in the row which will cause the other side to bleed in.

You can, for example, set the wrapping mode to something else where the interpolation will not take texels from the other side like `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
```